# Getting names of values passed as *args and **kwargs

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the value of prefix that may or may not be present in args or kwargs of a subclassed function.

Original function:

```
def list(self, prefix='', delimiter='', marker='', headers=None):
    pass
```

Subclassed function:

```
def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # get prefix from args[0] or kwargs['prefix']
    pass
```

I've tried:

```
kwargs.get('prefix', args[0])
```

but it fails if no args are passed.

I've tried:

```
prefix = ''

if len(args):
    prefix = args[0]

if 'prefix' in kwargs:
    prefix = kwargs['prefix']

if prefix != '':
    # Do something with the prefix
```

It works but it's not very elegant.

Also tried searching for a way to `zip()` the args with the kwargs. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "but it fails if no args are passed". Can you share the stacktrace ?

Comment: Yeah, ```args[0]``` fails if ```args = ()```

Comment: if you want that explicit function signature why not just use the more verbose signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work as expected:

```
def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
    prefix = kwargs.get('prefix', args[0] if args else '')
```

Comment: Excellent, didn't know that an if statement could go in get().

Comment: @nathancahill Actually you could use that everywhere! This is the so called shortcut conditional expression (also known as "ternary operator") available on Python since version 2.5. Check this link for more variations of that awesome feature: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html :)